# Patch and delete always returning 204: no content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, response, patch

I have two models: `card` and `lane`, where a `lane` has many `cards` and a `card` belongs to a `lane`.

```
def create
    lane = lane_find
    card = lane.cards.build(card_params)

    if card.save 
        respond_with lane, :include => :cards
    else
        respond_with({ :errors => card.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422, :location => nil)
    end
end

def update
    card = Card.find(params[:id])
    if card.update_attributes(card_params)
        respond_with card.lane
    else
        respond_with({ :errors => card.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422, :location => nil)
    end
end
```

(Note: `lane_find` is a private function not shown here but it simply does `Lane.find(params[:lane_id])`)

The intended behaviour is for the API client to receive a 422 error code when it does not save correctly, and to pass the errors alongs (such as being non-unique or being blank).

The strange thing is the create action works perfectly, as intended, while the update and destroy actions (not shown here) always return 204 on invalid input!

Testing manually on the command-line shows that the validations are set up correctly and `card.update_attributes(content: "")` returns `false`.

This is really bugging me! I would love your feedback :)

EDIT: card.rb

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :content, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}, :length => { minimum: 1 }, presence: true
    belongs_to :lane
end
```

Comment: show your card model card.rb

Comment: I realized that my answer does not address your problem, this might help https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11627

Comment: AMAZING--thank you! I used `render json: {...}` instead and it works perfectly. What a headache :O